# Creating Orange data table from json object

Tags: python, json, orange

I am trying to take a RestAPI json result and fill an Orange3 data table. All the examples I have seen use only discrete and continuous data types, but my json data has a string value. I convert the API result into a json object, but can't find a way to create string variables in the data table.
Is there an example out there that shows this?

Comment: Along with `DiscreteVariable` and `ContinuousVariable`, there seems to be a [`StringVariable`](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.variable.html#string-variables). Perhaps you can use that?

Comment: The problem is that StringVariables are not "primitive". StringVariables have to be "meta" data, but when I try to create a Domain object with a StringVariable.Make() in the Meta parameter is says it requires a primitive.

Comment: `Domain(..., metas=[StringVariable('name')])` doesn't work? `metas` must be a list of variables.

Comment: That was it. I was missing the "metas=",thx.